# How to pass value from href to input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need some guidance. I am trying to pass a value from `href` to an `input` value using getAttribute and it works fine, but if I used more than one `a` tag it only shows `href` attribute for the first one.

Pls, check the code snippet,

```js
function myFunction(event) { 
    document.getElementById("demo").value = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute('href');
}
```

```html
<a href="#2" onclick="myFunction(event)">test1</a>

<a href="#3" onclick="myFunction(event)">test2</a>

<input id="demo"></input>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your problem is the following:**

```
// That line is returning always the first <a> element, so you're getting always '#2'.
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
```

You can learn a little more here [`Element.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

---

You can pass the element directly to your function `myFunction`.

**Look this code snippet:**

```js
function myFunction(caller) {
  document.getElementById("demo").value = caller.getAttribute('href');
}
```

```html
<a href="#2" onclick="myFunction(this); event.target">test1</a>

<a href="#3" onclick="myFunction(this); event.target">test2</a>

<input id="demo"></input>
```

See, now the input is getting the right `href` value.

Comment: @AboudJouda :-)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically, you can do the same thing like this,

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll("a");

for (var i in a) {
  a[i].onclick = function() {
     document.getElementById("demo").value = this.getAttribute("href");
  };
}
```

```html
<a href="#1" >test1</a>
<a href="#2" >test2</a>

<input id="demo" />
```